# Is there any filter or action hook to remove layout classes from appearing in my templates?

Tags: theme-development, filters, hooks, block-editor, actions

With the new WordPress 6.1 core update, my site is now having a `is-layout-flow` class added to the layout.

Normally this wouldn't be a huge issue. However, we are using the WP API to feed the content into an app. That app uses some regex to parse/display data in the app and is expecting a certain layout to do so.

So, do we have the ability to remove these classes from our site?

Answer (score 4):

You may use the following code (either in your active theme's `functions.php` file or in a custom plugin):

```php
// This line is preferably be added to your theme's functions.php file
// with other add_theme_support() function calls.
add_theme_support( 'disable-layout-styles' );

// These two lines will probably not be necessary eventually
remove_filter( 'render_block', 'wp_render_layout_support_flag', 10, 2 );
remove_filter( 'render_block', 'gutenberg_render_layout_support_flag', 10, 2 );
```

The above code should remove the classes like `is-layout-flex`, `is-layout-flow` etc.

**Caution:** These are added for good reasons. So, unless you absolutely have to remove these, I'd suggest you to go through the following links before making the final decision:

- [A walk-through of layout classes in WordPress 6.1](https://developer.wordpress.org/news/2023/01/a-walk-through-of-layout-classes-in-wordpress-6-1/)
- [Updated editor layout support in 6.1 after refactor](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/10/10/updated-editor-layout-support-in-6-1-after-refactor/)